# How to modify a content of particular line in a file using Shell scripting, when the text in that line is repeated many time in other lines as well

Tags: shell-script

How to modify a content of particular line in a file using Shell scripting, when the text in that line is repeated many time in other lines as well.
For example in the file i have :

```
##############################
[CC-COARSEGRID-PRECONDITIONER]
##############################
# Relaxation parameter
domega = 1.0
##############
[CC-PRECONDMK]
##############
# Relaxation parameter
domega = 0.9
```

I want to change the last line to:
domega = 0.4

Comment: if it is always the last line `sed -i -e '$s/=.*$/= 0.4/' file`

Answer (score 2):

You could use `sed`/`tac`:

```
tac file | sed '0,/domega = .*/s/domega = .*/domega = 0.4/' | tac
```

- `tac file` reverses the file.
- `0,/domega = .*/` only do the replacement between the line 0 and the first occurence of `domega` (is now the last).
- `s/domega = .*/domega = 0.4/` then do the relacement.
- `tac` reverses again.